# Load a resource (e.g. JavaScript script) from multiple locations as fallback?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder if there's a way to tell browser load  a resource like a *JavaScript script* from server A (e.g. a CDN which has many benefits) and if it was not successful load it from server B (which can be my own server or so) as a fallback solution.

Comment: Yes that will do, but I thought there would be a better way built into the `HTML`  itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the JavaScript used in browsers has objects that appear globally.
It detects the presence or absence, and if not, writes `<script>` with `document.write`.

```js
console.log($.fn.jquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.5/jquery.notfound.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write(`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>`)</script>
```

If async is applied, the timing of loading will be "somewhere before onload". So, it is a flow of setting an event on `window.onload` and generating a  element in the DOM if it is not loaded.

Comment: That will do, but I thought there would be a better way built into the HTML itself. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @MaskedMan As far as read the HTML Standard, it is not to be in the standard.